# nhibernate does not release memory after session closes

Tags: nhibernate

I am using NHibernate 2.2 with c# 3.5 and VS2008,

The problem is when I close the Nhibernate Session object, the memory is not released. 
even I call GC.Collect() after every close, but nothing is getting freed up

How can I force NHibernate to release the objects loaded in session when session is closed?

thanks

Comment: I have this EXACT problem - and it is a problem but there seems to be massive denial from other nhib users!

Answer (score 1):

Use Dispose instead of close. (Not only for Session, but for every object implementing IDisposable in .net)

Comment: Can it be an issue in the surrounding code? How do you know the memory is not cleaned up, by a profiler?

Comment: i watched it from Windows Task Manager, the memory goes high only, when i run GC.Collect() it goes down a bit (around 1 or 2 MB) , but not the whole memory released

Comment: Some remarks: 1. Disposable objects cannot be cleaned by the garbage collection at once many times. 2. The memory taken by the application is made available for other applications at a different speed than realesing individual objects to prevent fragmentation. 3. You cannot view the individual memory print of objects in windows task manager. 4. More than 1/2 MB memory in a single session sounds like a lot (too much data loaded). 5. You can better download some kind of profiler tool (I use Ants memory profiler) to have a more accurate view, before you start debugging the GC itself

Comment: is there any trick or technique that i can use to free this memory sooner ? i want to deploy my application on PC's with 512MB Ram ,so memory management should be better

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things which could prevent garbage collection actually occurring even if you call `GC.Collect();`. For example if other objects which are still alive and in use are holding a reference to something you no longer want, then the object will be kept alive.

Also don't forget that a portion of the memory used will be the objects that NHibernate has returned fro the database for you.